# AngularJs css live changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a features built on angularjs, it's a dropdown option where user can do changes of the `status` and changes will be reflected on status. Here is my html snippet:

The status

```
<td data-title="'Status'"><span  class="label label-sm label-{{orders.state}}">{{orders.state}}</span></td>
```

The DropDown options

```
<ui-select ng-model="state.selected" ng-change="openModal(state.selected.name,orders.order_id)" ng-if="orders.state == 'Paid'" theme="selectize" ng-disabled="disabled" style="width: 300px;">
        <ui-select-match  placeholder="Fullfilment status">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="state in states | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind-html="state.name | highlight: $select.search"></span>
</ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

The `ng-click` will trigger a post request to the server as follow:

```
myApp.controller('ChgResvCtrl',['$scope','$modalInstance','$state','content','Account','ngNotify',function($scope,$modalInstance,$state,content,Account,ngNotify){

    $scope.status = content.status;
    $scope.status_oid = content.orderid;

    $scope.confirmChg = function(oid,status){
        Account.merchantSetStatus(oid,status)
           .then(function(response){
                ngNotify.set('Status changed successfully', {
                type: 'info',
                position: 'bottom',
                duration: 2000
            });

           })
           .catch(function(response){

           })  
    }
    $scope.cancel = function () {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}]);
```

The response that I receive is `{status:'Fullfilled',success:true}`.
The question is, how can I hide the `dropdown` option once I received an response.

Also How can I replace the `{{orders.state}}` with response status that I received of the html `<span  class="label label-sm label-{{orders.state}}">{{orders.state}}</span>`

ie: `label-Paid(current) ---> label-Fullfilled(from response)`

Thanks!!

Comment: create a scope variable inside control and make it false once you get the response make it true. you that variable to show or hide and same thing with orders.state

Comment: @SusheelSingh how about `order.state`? It's not hide or show, but changes in state. ie initially the status is `Paid` once the response is received, status should change to `Fullfilled`. Changing the status eventually change the css. That's why I set css  as `label-{{order.state}}`

Comment: yes same thing declare it as paid and changed the same scoped variable to fullfilled once you receive the response.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, for the status, if you have $scope.orders.state defined:

```
<td data-title="'Status'"><span ng-class="getClass()" class="label label-sm">{{orders.state}}</span></td>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.getClass = function() {
    return 'label-' + $scope.orders.state;
}
```

For hiding the dropdown just create a variable and use it with ng-show or ng-hide.

Comment: let me know how it went!